# Group into nested array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, grouping

I have an array of categories:

```
[
  { categoryId: '01', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' },
  { categoryId: '010', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' },
  { categoryId: '01001', categoryName: 'Cement' },
  { categoryId: '01002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' },
  { categoryId: '01003', categoryName: 'Kalkvaror' },
  { categoryId: '011', categoryName: 'Byggnadsblock och ballast' },
  { categoryId: '01101', categoryName: 'Betongblock' },
  { categoryId: '01102', categoryName: 'Tegel' },
  { categoryId: '02', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' },
  { categoryId: '020', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' },
  { categoryId: '02001', categoryName: 'Cement' },
  { categoryId: '02002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' }
......
]
```

And an array of products:

```
[
  {
    productNumber: '01405',
    productName: 'SERVALAC AQUA BLANK - Utg�tt'
  },
  {
    productNumber: '01405',
    productName: 'SERVALAC AQUA HALVBLANK - Utg�tt'
  },
  {
    productNumber: '03405',
    productName: 'SERVALAC AQUA HALVBLANK - Utg�tt'
  },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE GT-20 - UTG�TT' },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE 7 - UTG�TT' },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE 7 - UTG�TT' },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE 7 - UTG�TT' },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE 5 - UTG�TT' },
  { productNumber: '03404', productName: 'SCOTTE 20 - UTG�TT' },
......
]
```

I want to group each product in the corresponding category.
The categories should be also grouped like this: main category (all the categories with 2 digits), second category (with 3 digits) and the next one (with 5 digits).
Each product should be added to the corresponding main category, second and third category.

The result should be like this:

```
{
    "id":"01",
    "categoryName":"Byggmaterial",
    "items":[
        {
            "id":"010",
            "categoryName":"Bindemedel och bruk",
            "items": [
                {
                   "id":"01001",
                    "categoryName":"Cement",
                    "products": [
                          {
                             "productNumber":"01001",
                             "productName":"Tunnfog och Tunnputsbruk A"
                          },
                          {
                             "productNumber":"01001",
                             "productName":"Tunnfog"
                          },
                          .......
                    ]       
        }
                    ]       
        },
```

I'm stuck so I need help.
I've tried with "for loop" inside "for loop", but I only succeeded to group all the products in main category.

```
{"id":"01","categoryName":"Byggmaterial","items":[{"productNumber":"01001","productName":"Tunnfog och Tunnputsbruk A"},{"productNumber":"01001","productName":"Lagningsmassa fin"},{"productNumber":"01399","productName":"Golvfoam Premium MFR"}, {"productNumber":"01199","productName":"THERMOMUR 350 STD SLUTET"}, {"productNumber":"01701","productName":"Adva Flow 484"},{"productNumber":"01706","productName":"Pieri Decobio C-23"}
```

Is there any other solution then "for loop"? I think that I cannot get the wanted result with only for loop.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have some categories and products which match?

Comment: @NinaScholz: each product matches with a main category, also with a second category and a third category. If the productNumber is "01001" for ex, it matches with main category "01", second category "010" and third one "01001".

Comment: yes, yes, but the product does not match with the given categories.

Comment: I couldn't paste all the products or all the categories here, but each product belongs to a given category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two mutually recursive helper functions: one that selects subcategories for the given category:

```
function items(cid, level) {
    return categories
        .filter(c => c.categoryId.startsWith(cid) && c.categoryId.length === level)
        .map(process)
}
```

and one that processes a category:

```
function process(cat) {
    let cid = cat?.categoryId || ''

    switch (cid.length) {
        case 0:
            return {...cat, items: items(cid, 2)}
        case 2:
            return {...cat, items: items(cid, 3)}
        case 3:
            return {...cat, items: items(cid, 5)}
        case 5:
            return {
                ...cat,
                products: products.filter(p => p.productNumber.startsWith(cid))
            }
    }
}
```

Finally, just invoke `process()` with no arguments.

Comment: I used your solution, it works perfect and it fits to my needs, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the catalog by preserving all `categoryId` which points to `items` and later push the products to the category.

```js
const
    categories = [{ categoryId: '01', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' }, { categoryId: '010', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' }, { categoryId: '01001', categoryName: 'Cement' }, { categoryId: '01002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' }, { categoryId: '01003', categoryName: 'Kalkvaror' }, { categoryId: '011', categoryName: 'Byggnadsblock och ballast' }, { categoryId: '01101', categoryName: 'Betongblock' }, { categoryId: '01102', categoryName: 'Tegel' }, { categoryId: '02', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' }, { categoryId: '020', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' }, { categoryId: '02001', categoryName: 'Cement' }, { categoryId: '02002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' }],
    products = [{ productNumber: "01001", productName: "Tunnfog och Tunnputsbruk A" }, { productNumber: "01001", productName: "Tunnfog" }],
    catalog = categories.reduce((r, { categoryId, categoryName }) => {
        let i = categoryId.length;
        do {
            const key = categoryId.slice(0, i);
            if (key in r) {
                (r[key].items ??= []).push(r[categoryId] = { categoryId, categoryName });
                return r;
            }
        } while (--i)
        r.items.push(r[categoryId] = { categoryId, categoryName });
        return r;
    }, { items: [] });

products.forEach(o => (catalog[o.productNumber].product ??= []).push(o));

console.log(catalog.items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test the solution. This is what I want, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If product numbers can be longer than category numbers, then maybe also look up the category iteratively:

```js
function hierarchy(categories, products) {
    function parent(s) {
        while (!map.has(s)) s = s.slice(0, -1);
        return map.get(s);
    }
    const root = { items: [] };
    const map = new Map(categories.map(({categoryId: id, ...rest}) => [id, { id, ...rest }])).set("", root);
    for (const cat of categories) {
        (parent(cat.categoryId.slice(0, -1)).items ??= []).push(map.get(cat.categoryId));
    }
    for (const prod of products) {
        (parent(prod.productNumber).products ??= []).push(prod);
    }
    return root.items;
}

// Demo
const categories = [
  { categoryId: '01', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' },
  { categoryId: '010', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' },
  { categoryId: '01001', categoryName: 'Cement' },
  { categoryId: '01002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' },
  { categoryId: '01003', categoryName: 'Kalkvaror' },
  { categoryId: '011', categoryName: 'Byggnadsblock och ballast' },
  { categoryId: '01101', categoryName: 'Betongblock' },
  { categoryId: '01102', categoryName: 'Tegel' },
  { categoryId: '02', categoryName: 'Byggmaterial' },
  { categoryId: '020', categoryName: 'Bindemedel och bruk' },
  { categoryId: '02001', categoryName: 'Cement' },
  { categoryId: '02002', categoryName: 'Bruksbindemedel' }
];

const products  = [
  { productNumber: '01001', productName: 'Tunnfog och Tunnputsbruk A' },
  { productNumber: '01001',  productName: 'Tunnfog' },
];

const forest = hierarchy(categories, products);
console.log(forest);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Your solution seems to be exactly what I want, but I need to test first. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```js
const getNextPrefixLength = (prefix) =>
  // Needed because level 3 has 5 chars
  prefix.length + (prefix.length === 3 ? 2 : 1);

const getCategoriesByPrefix = (idPrefix) =>
  categories.filter(
    ({ categoryId }) =>
      categoryId.length === getNextPrefixLength(idPrefix) &&
      categoryId.startsWith(idPrefix)
  );

const getGroupedCategoryRecursively = ({ categoryId: id, categoryName }) => ({
  id,
  categoryName,
  items: getCategoriesByPrefix(id).map(getGroupedCategoryRecursively),
});

const result = getCategoriesByPrefix("0").map(getGroupedCategoryRecursively);
```